# How to tell rails to compress my sass css file with the sass-rails gem?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

In the top of my `application.html` layout, i've removed the link to the default `application.css` and linked my own style sheet.

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "home", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

I noticed that the css compression that comes with the sass-rails gem (removing white space and comments) no longer takes effect. How do I tell rails to do compress my css.scss file?

Also, are there are any other features I am losing by using my own stylesheet as opposed to the `application.css` given to me?

Comment: The CSS compression is usually used in the production environment, the development does not compress the CSS generated by SASS (usually). Check if your `config/environments/production.rb` file contains the following line `config.assets.compress = true`

Comment: Oh, I have been only testing it through my local server. Let me try pushing it to heroku to see if it makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

Add "--style=compressed" to callout